# Is this a bug in RegionEqual?

Tags: regions, geometry

```
$Version
```

---

```
"13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)"
```

Is this a bug or I am missing something?

Correct result:

```
ImplicitRegion[x <= 1/3 && y == -x, {x, y}];
HalfLine[{1/3, -1/3}, {-1, 1}];
RegionEqual[%%, %]
```

---

```
True
```

Returns back the input:

```
ImplicitRegion[x <= 1/3 && y == -x, {x, y}];
HalfLine[{1/3, -1/3}, {0, 0}];
RegionEqual[%%, %]
```

---

```
RegionEqual[ImplicitRegion[x <= 1/3 && y == -x, {x, y}], 
 HalfLine[{1/3, -(1/3)}, {0, 0}]]
```

Incorrect result:

```
ImplicitRegion[x <= 1/3 && y == -x, {x, y}]
HalfLine[{1/3, -1/3}, {1/4, -1/4}]
RegionEqual[%%, %]
```

---

```
False
```

Comment: `RegionEqual[ImplicitRegion[x <= 1/3 && y == -x, {x, y}], 
 HalfLine[{{1/3, -(1/3)}, {0, 0}}]]` and `RegionEqual[ImplicitRegion[x <= 1/3 && y == -x, {x, y}],
 HalfLine[{{1/3, -1/3}, {1/4, -1/4}}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HalfLine[{x1,y1},{v1,v2}]` is the half-line start from `{x1,y1}` with the direction `{v1,v2}`.

```
RegionEqual[HalfLine[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}], 
 HalfLine[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2} - {x1, y1}]]
```

> `True`

For the comment.

```
(* Version11.3, 12.2, 12.3.1,13.3.1,14.0 *)
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2 x}, {x, y}];
reg2 = Line[{{1/3, -1/3}, {1/2, 0}}];
{RegionWithin[reg2, reg1], RegionWithin[reg1, reg2]}
```

> `True,False`.

And all of the above versions also return wrong result when we run

```
RegionEqual[reg1, reg2]
```

> `False`.

It is a bug.

Comment: And what about this? Is this a bug? `RegionEqual[
 ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2 x}, {x, y}], 
 Line[{{1/3, -1/3}, {1/2, 0}}]]` It outputs `False`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan  I test version 11.3,12.2,12.3.1, 13.3.1,14, It must be a bug.

Comment: This is the link to the actual bug: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297270/is-this-a-bug-in-regionequal-or-somewhere-else