# Is this a bug in RegionEqual or something else?

Tags: regions, geometry

Is this a bug or I am missing something again?
I ran the following code on a fresh kernel and each time it outputs randomly different result consisting of all combination `{True, True}`, `{True, False}`, `{False, True}`, `{False`, `False}`.

But I think it should output always `{True, True}`.

```
Do[Print[{RegionEqual[
    ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2 x}, {x, y}], 
    Line[{{1/3, -1/3}, {1/2, 0}}]], 
   RegionEqual[
    ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2 x}, {x, y}], 
    Line[{{1/2, 0}, {1/3, -1/3}}]]}], {i, 10}]
```

---

```
{False,True}

{True,False}

{False,True}

{False,True}

{True,True}

{False,False}

{False,False}

{False,False}

{False,False}

{False,False}
```

My version:

```
$Version
```

---

```
"13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)"
```

Answer (score 2):

It uses randomness somewhere in its internal checks. Seed the random number generator, each time, you get consistent results (e.g. `{True, False}` every iteration), although not necessary correct results.

```
Do[
 SeedRandom[20];
 Print[{RegionEqual[
    ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2  x}, {x, y}], 
    Line[{{1/3, -1/3}, {1/2, 0}}]], 
   RegionEqual[
    ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2  x}, {x, y}], 
    Line[{{1/2, 0}, {1/3, -1/3}}]]}], {i, 10}]
(*
{True,True}

{True,True}

{True,True}

{True,True}

{True,True}

{True,True}

{True,True}

{True,True}

{True,True}

{True,True}
*)
```

The following shows the line and its reversal are not computationally equivalent -- that is, we get different answers with the same random seed.

```
With[{seed = 4},
 {
  SeedRandom[seed];
  RegionEqual[
   ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2  x}, {x, y}], 
   Line[{{1/3, -1/3}, {1/2, 0}}]],
  SeedRandom[seed];
  RegionEqual[
   ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2  x}, {x, y}], 
   Line[{{1/2, 0}, {1/3, -1/3}}]]}
 ]

(* {True, False} *)
```

The internals can't be `Trace[]`-d it seems, so I think the only thing to do is to report it Wolfram.

*Possible workaround for exact regions*

Add a no-op condition depending on a parameter (`Element[a, Reals]`):

```
Do[Print[{
   RegionEqual[
    ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2  x && 
       Element[a, Reals]}, {x, y}],
    Line[{{1/3, -1/3}, {1/2, 0}}]], 
   RegionEqual[
    ImplicitRegion[{1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2  x && 
       Element[a, Reals]}, {x, y}],
    Line[{{1/2, 0}, {1/3, -1/3}}]]}], {i, 10}]

(* < all are {True, True} > *)
```

Comment: It must be a serious bug. What does it have anything with randomness? Regions are equal or are not equal.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I'd say the output in the OP, from a user's point of view, implies it should be considered a bug. Your point, imo, is also an argument that it is a design choice, because, as you say, what does it have to with randomness? One possibility is that there does not exist a robust, deterministic, relatively quick algorithm for region equality.