# Converting implicit region to line

Tags: graphics, regions

How to convert `ImplicitRegion` to `Line`, `InfiniteLine` or `HalfLine`?

I did it manually:

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] & /@ {{x <= 1/3 && 
      y == -x}, {x == 1/3 && y <= -(1/3)}, {1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && 
      y == -1 + 2 x}, {x <= 1/2 && y == 1 - 2 x}, {x >= 1/2 && 
      y == 0}, {2 x + 3 y == 1}};

line = {HalfLine[{{1/3, -1/3}, {0, 0}}], 
   HalfLine[{{1/3, -1/3}, {1/3, -1}}], Line[{{1/3, -1/3}, {1/2, 0}}], 
   HalfLine[{{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}], HalfLine[{{1/2, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
   InfiniteLine[{{0, 1/3}, {1, -1/3}}]};

RegionEqual @@@ Transpose[{ir, line}]

Show[Region[#, PlotRange -> 3] & /@ ir, 
Graphics[{Dashed, line}, PlotRange -> 3]]
```

---

```
{True, True, True, True, True, True}
```

[image]

Notice that the third `True` can be sometimes `False` due to this bug in [`RegionEqual`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297270/is-this-a-bug-in-regionequal-or-something-else) but `True` is the correct result.

Also notice that definition of `HalfLine` or `InfiniteLine` are not unique, I will accept any form.

There is also:

```
RegionConvert[HalfLine[{{1/3, -1/3}, {0, 0}}], "Implicit"]
```

---

```
ImplicitRegion[X + Y == 0 && X <= 2/3 + Y, {X, Y}]
```

But I think it only converts lines to implicit region but not the other way.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
transform[reg_] := 
  Module[{pair, type},
 {pt1, pt2} = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} /. 
     FindInstance[{{x1, y1} ∈ reg, {x2, y2} ∈ 
         reg, {x1, y1} != {x2, y2}}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}][[1]];
   type = 
    First@RegionBounds[
      ImplicitRegion[pt1 + t     (pt2 - pt1) ∈ reg, {t}]];
   ReplaceAll[type
    , {{-∞, a_} /; a ∈ Reals :> 
      HalfLine[pt1 + t     (pt2 - pt1) /. t -> a, 
       Sign[-∞]    (pt2 - pt1)]
     , {a_, ∞} /; a ∈ Reals :> 
      HalfLine[pt1 + t     (pt2 - pt1) /. t -> a, 
       Sign[∞]    (pt2 - pt1)]
     , {-∞, ∞} :> 
      InfiniteLine[pt1 + t     (pt2 - pt1) /. t -> 1, 
       Sign[∞]    (pt2 - pt1)]
     , {a_, b_} /; a ∈ Reals && b ∈ Reals :> 
      Line[{pt1 + t     (pt2 - pt1) /. t -> a, 
        pt1 + t     (pt2 - pt1) /. t -> b}
       ]}]];
ir = ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] & /@ {{x <= 1/3 && 
      y == -x}, {x == 1/3 && y <= -(1/3)}, {1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && 
      y == -1 + 2     x}, {x <= 1/2 && y == 1 - 2     x}, {x >= 1/2 &&
       y == 0}, {2     x + 3     y == 1}};
result = transform /@ ir
Graphics[result, PlotRange -> 2]
```

> `{HalfLine[{1/3, -(1/3)}, {-1, 1}], HalfLine[{1/3, -(1/3)}, {0, -1}],  Line[{{1/3, -(1/3)}, {1/2, 0}}], HalfLine[{1/2, 0}, {-1, 2}],  HalfLine[{1/2, 0}, {1, 0}], InfiniteLine[{1, -(1/3)}, {1, -(2/3)}]}`

[image]

**Original**

Only one way for `Line`,using `RegionBounds`.

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2  x, {x, y}];
(* line1=Line[{{MinValue[x,{x,y}∈reg],MinValue[y,{x,y}\
∈reg]},{MaxValue[x,{x,y}∈reg],MaxValue[y,{x,y}\
∈reg]}}]; *)
line2 = Line@Transpose@RegionBounds[reg1]
Graphics[{DiscretizeRegion@reg1, Opacity[.2], Pink, 
  AbsoluteThickness[20], line2}]
```

[image]

```
Transpose /@ RegionBounds /@ ir
```

> `{{{-∞, -(1/3)}, {1/3, ∞}}, {{1/ 3, -∞}, {1/3, -(1/3)}}, {{1/3, -(1/3)}, {1/2,  0}}, {{-∞, 0}, {1/2, ∞}}, {{1/2,  0}, {∞,  0}}, {{-∞, -∞}, {∞, ∞}}}`

- Need to be updated.

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] & /@ {{x <= 1/3 && 
      y == -x}, {x == 1/3 && y <= -(1/3)}, {1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && 
      y == -1 + 2     x}, {x <= 1/2 && y == 1 - 2     x}, {x >= 1/2 &&
       y == 0}, {2     x + 3     y == 1}};
pairs = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} /. 
     FindInstance[{{x1, y1} ∈ #, {x2, y2} ∈ #, {x1, 
          y1} != {x2, y2}}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}][[1]] & /@ ir;
MapThread[
 First@RegionBounds[
    ImplicitRegion[#[[1]] + 
       t  (#[[2]] - #[[1]]) ∈ #2, {t}]] &, {pairs, ir}]
```

> `{{-∞, 1}, {-∞, 1}, {0, 1}, {-∞,  1}, {0, ∞}, {-∞, ∞}}`